# Rewrite URL in Apache while retaining query string and forwarding to subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my first time posting and I really appreciate the help.

I want to redirect a sub-domain to a folder and rewrite it to the query string **(internally - without the browser address changing)** but also retain the balance (if any) of the query string.

This should be done using **Apache mod_rewrite.**

It should also exclude the base domain and www extension (as that points to the root directory).

I have done everything necessary from the DNS (wildcard setup) and vhosts and do not want a mod_proxy approach

Here is exactly how I want it to work.

> www.mysite.com to root directory 
>   mysite.com to root directory

user1.mysite.com to go to app directory and query string to append user=user1 (Without the browser address changing)

eg -

```
user1.mysite.com should resolve (internally) to mysite.com/myApp/index.php?user=user1
user2.mysite.com should resolve (internally) to mysite.com/myApp/index.php?user=user2

user1.mysite.com/mypage.php should resolve (internally) to mysite.com/myApp/mypage.php?user=user1
user1.mysite.com/mypage.php?myval=whateverval should resolve (internally) to mysite.com/myApp/mypage.php?user=user1&?myval=whateverval
```

The existing code I have is as follows but does not work implicitly (the browser addressbar changes). Can someone please help me?

Thanks,
Sheran

Comment: Do `user1.mysite.com` and `mysite.com` hosted on same host and have same DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use mod_proxy, you need to point all of your wildcard subdomains to the same document root as your main domain. You can do this using `ServerAlias *.mysite.com` in your vhost setup for `www.mysite.com`. Then in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(mypage\.php)?$ /myApp/index.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: mypage.php can be any page in the MyApp directory, I just want to retain the page accessed.